# Printing a div with HTML in a Partial view in mvc 4 with C# using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to show a print in table format(design ) in c# mvc.

The problem is that i am getting only the content and not in table format..

This is my Print button.

```
<input id="printdiv" type="submit" value="Print" onclick="return PrintDiv();" />
```

This is my Partial view div.

```
<div id="dvmismatch" style="display :none;">
        @Html.Partial("_MismatchVendorList", Model)
    </div>
```

This is my Script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();   
    function PrintDiv() {
        $("#dvmismatch").show();
        $("#dvmismatch").print();
        $("#dvmismatch").hide();

        }       

</script>
```

plz give me the Suggestions...

i want to Print a div with HTML in a Partial view in mvc 4 with C# using JavaScript..But showing only the table Content. Not the Content with Table Format????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Try This
>
> Javascript

```
<script>
function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
</script>
```

> Button

```
<input id="printdiv" type="submit" value="Print" onclick="printContent('dvmismatch')" />
```

> This is Partial view div.

```
<div id="dvmismatch" style="display :none;">
        @Html.Partial("_MismatchVendorList", Model)
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that regenerating the HTML seems to undo the javascript programming already assigned.